# VIM: Search and replace $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] with $server_name

Tags: vim, replace

Hmm.. can't figure this one out. I'm new to Vim and I believe it thinks that $ is one word, _SERVER another and so on. So when I search for the whole string, it doesn't find it. How do I work around this problem?

I tried

```
:%s#$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']#$server_name#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your brackets or they describe a character class.

```
%s/$_SERVER\['SERVER_NAME'\]/$server_name/g
```

Comment: Thanks regality, it worked. Is this true for all brackets? Are there other characters that need to be escapted as well? Thanks again!

Comment: Search and replace uses regular expressions, here's a website that will go into depth on pattern matching: http://vimregex.com/

Comment: @FrankVilea In this case you could also use `%s#\V$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']#$server_name#`. `\V` (very no-magic) modifier makes any character except backslash interpreted literally. Most useful in scripts or with addition to pasting from register with `<C-r>{register}`.